# Four equations for the same number?

Tags: lateral-thinking

Using creative thinking can you show

> 9 = 4
>
> 9 = 8
>
> 9 = 14
>
> 9 = 24

All four equations follow the same logic/method.

While you are at it can you also show (same logic)

> 55 = 4

Hint:

> Think Roman Numeral for LHS

Comment: For the first four, multiply RHS by 9 and take the sum of digits :P

Comment: The logic that applies to all is that the equality is false.

Comment: It strikes me as potentially significant that in A0Z25 the RHS of each equation corresponds to a vowel (E, I, O, Y, then E again)...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this is the reasoning

> IX = $\frac{2}{3}$ of the word S**IX** = $\frac{2}{3} \times 6 = 4$
>  IX = $\frac{2}{9}$ of THIRTY S**IX** = $\frac{2}{9} \times 36 = 8$
>  IX = $\frac{1}{4}$ of FIFTY  S**IX** = $\frac{1}{4} \times 56 = 14$
>  IX = $\frac{2}{5}$ of S**IX**TY = $\frac{2}{5} \times 60 = 24$

Bonus

> LV = $\frac{1}{3}$ of TWE**LV**E = $\frac{1}{3} \times 12 = 4$

Comment: And it is finally solved!!  Kudos.